# Upgrading to Sql Server Express R2 Advanced Services in Middle of Development

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2010

I am currently developing, from the ground up, my first asp.net website.  After implementing many of the more basic features for my site I have run into a problem with Visual Basic 2010's SQL Server 2008 Express. I want to have search with my site so users can look for specific records in my database, and from what I have researched Full-Text Search is the best way to go (right?). It wasn't until I tried to test my code that I realized the default Express edition doesn't have Full-Text Search enabled.  My question is a.) how can I upgrade to the SQL Server Advanced Services in the middle of development without losing my Database's, and b.) what download should I use, because right now I'm thinking http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?Id=25174.

I really want to be sure that I am not only installing the right software, but that I won't completely screw up my project in the process.  Along those lines, should I backup my database's and then uninstall my original version of SQL Server before downloading the Advanced Services version?  I would really appreciate some help here because I have had massive headaches in the past trying to upgrade Microsoft software and just want a smooth transition.

Comment: "*...should I backup...?*"  The answer to this question is always "*yes, you should* always *backup up* everything" (not just your databases) before you do an install or upgrade.  Especially if you care about what's on your system and/or have concerns.  Always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it took me the entirety of a day, but I solved this! First I had to uninstall EVERYTHING regarding SQL Server.  Then I downloaded http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?Id=25174 (X86 since I am on Vista) and used .\SQLEXPRESS as my Instance Name.  Once it was done installing I had to delete the SQLEXPRESS folder in 'C:\Users[Your computer's name!]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data' to get my old connections to work! Then I could create databases in SQL Server Management Studio that had Full Text enabled.